# How do you draw freehand (like a pencil tool) in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: linux-mint, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, drawing, wacom-one

How do you draw freehand in LibreOffice Writer? Is there a "pencil tool"? I have a Wacom tablet and I want to use it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `Drawing Bar - Freeform Line`.

You can show the toolbar by select following option.
View -> Toolbars -> Drawing
[image]

Or by the 'Show Draw Function` symbol in upper right if it exists.

After open the Drawing Toolbar there will be a `Freeform Line` Option under `Curves and Polygons`.

[image]

Edit:
Adding link to [LibreOffice Help - Drawing Bar](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/sdraw/main0210.html)